# How to Handle Mozilla Firefox asking Geo location popup again and again in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried the Geo location service in all the browser working fine except the Mozilla Firefox, where it asks for the location again and gain even after allowing it

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox should store individual site permissions (allow/block) indefinitely, you shouldn't have to re-enter them.

Showing "Remember this decision"
[image: Showing the checkbox Remember this decision]

There may be **problem** storing site permissions if you are using local file OR a private window. Please as per below image.

"Remember this decision" not appear
[image: Remember this decision not appear]

For [More detail](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1115686)

Answer (score 1):

Probably because Firefox is in private mode. What you can do, use [`navigator.geolocation.watchPosition()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition) and store the position in a variable:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

var position = null;

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation && !position) {
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(currentPosition) {
            position = currentPosition;
        }, function(error) {
            alert(error)
        });
    }
};

function showPosition() {
    if (position) {
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    } else {
         x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported or authorized.";
    }
};

getLocation();
```

```html
<button onclick="showPosition()">Try It</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

If the browser supports geolocation and if the user authorizes it. Each time you will call showPosition() you will display the current coordinates;

Note that the snippet above may not works because it's embeded, please try in real dev web page.